# How to reduce CPU usage from own C programms

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi3, cpu-usage

User C programm do cpu usage of 200% on my RPi3+. I noticed it because I wondered about the hight temperature.

I checked my other Pis with other own written C programms. Nearly the same: CPU usage 100% (Pi3 but no plus). When I kill/stop just this programm, the CPU usage and temperature drop down.

In the while(1) loop i check the gpio state (connected to a button) . If it pressed i do things depending on duration that the button is pressed. For expample print over cups or delete/change mysql data.

I read something about select() but i didnt understood the context or usage.
But I understood that slowering the loop with sleeps ist not the way of art.

```
...
while(1)
{
   if (digitalRead(butPin)) // Button is released if this returns 1
   {
       digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);     // Regular LED off
   }
   else 
   {
      //evalute button press
      ......
   }
...
```

All works fine and the pi response fast usally. But for this easy work the pi is too hot. So it also needs too much power.

**EDIT:**

## First try: add usleep() to the end of while(1)

this reduce the CPU usage but not to low level.

`usleep(0)`     => 200%

`usleep(5)`     => 111%

`usleep(100)` => 105%

`usleep(5000)` => 100%

(on Raspberry 3+)

[Top RPI3+ CPU 200%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEWc4.jpg)

Comment: Just curious.. what's 200% usage? Does it grab another RPI from the shelf?

Comment: Try searching for "event-driven programming".

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's a dual-core processor. (Though I also don't understand how one busy loop pulls down two cores.)

Comment: As for the question... use interrupts instead of a busy loop to check your input. And go to a lower power state while waiting (`wfi`? not sure about your environment.)

Comment: The problem is that you are [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science))) without any delay between loops.
You could start by adding some `nanosleep()` in the `while` loop. (see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/nanosleep-wont-sleep-short-time)

Comment: thx to all. i will use your key words (event-driven programming, interruption) for farther searching.. i will update when get a successfull solution

Comment: one thing i don't understand. if i use interrupts i still need a main loop. Why this will be less cpu intensive? Would be the programm set to sleep mode or where comes the postiv effect from?

Comment: I assume there is more to your program than you wrote. The `usleep` should be one solution to your problem. But since you initially have 200% CPU and the fix lead you to 100% CPU I bet there is another thread with a loop having the same problem. Or else I can't explain why a single threaded application can use two cores at the same time.

Comment: You are so right! i tried to simplify to keep it easy to explain. Yes, the Rpi3+ that shows 200% starts a thread with a busy wait too.
The other Rpi3 (no plus) that shows 100% doesn't start threads. Pitty, i mixed it up. But you all firgued out the right diretion. Now i have to understand how to use events/interrupts and where the while(1) will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You may let the OS spare resources (compute other things) by telling your program to sleep.

```
usleep(int timeInMicroseconds);
```

this will make the program sleep for timeInMicroseconds.

As your program take in account Button pushes sleeping for a even a few milliseconds shouldn't make your program less efficient in detecting pushes.

The more your program will sleep the more it will release the CPU, but also be less reactive to detect your pushes (and even doesn't detect them if the sleep period is too long). It's a balance; some trial and error should give you a good value.

```
#include <unistd.h>

while(1)
{
   if (digitalRead(butPin)) // Button is released if this returns 1
   {
       digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);     // Regular LED off
   }
   else 
   {

   }
   usleep(5000); //Sleep for 5ms
}
```

Another option would be to use interruption: 
[Interruption with wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/).

Comment: @ThomasJager: OK — I didn't check for prior editions of the answer.  I'll remove my comment, I suppose, though there's some possibly useful information there.  …Nah, it goes…  Maybe your comment has been overtaken by changes too?